# RemoveAll predicate using identification via IsAssignableFrom

Tags: c#, generic-list, removeall, reflection

I implemented an extension method to `List<T>`. In that extension method, there is a predicate where I fail to express what I want the predicate to do. I formulated a set of tests to elaborate my intentions.
`IsAssignableFrom` does somehow not identify interfaces nor childclasses - or (more likely) I'm using it wrong. The test `ShouldRemove_All` does not remove anything. The Test `ShouldRemove_RA_AND_RAA` removes only RA. The third test passes.

Here is the code - how do I need to adapt the extension method in order to pass all the tests?

The code does compile and can be executed - all it needs is a project with NUnit.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Text;

namespace SystemTools
{

    public static class ListExtension
    {
        public static int RemoveAllOfType<T>(this List<T> list, Type removeable)
        {
            Predicate<T> match = (x) =>
            {
                return x.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(removeable);
            };
            return list.RemoveAll(match);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    class ListExtension_Test
    {
        private interface IRoot { }
        private class Child_RA : IRoot { }
        private class Child_RB : IRoot { }
        private class Child_RAA : Child_RA { }

        List<IRoot> scenario;
        int sumofelements, RA, RB, RAA;

        private String DebugString(List<IRoot> list)
        {
            StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(list.Count * 10);
            ret.Append("Remaining: '");
            Boolean atleastone = false;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (atleastone) ret.Append(", ");
                ret.Append(item.GetType().Name);
                atleastone = true;
            }
            ret.Append("'");
            return ret.ToString();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            RB = 1; RA = 2; RAA = 3;
            sumofelements = RB + RA + RAA;
            scenario = new List<IRoot>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= RB; i++) scenario.Add(new Child_RB());
            for (int i = 1; i <= RA; i++) scenario.Add(new Child_RA());
            for (int i = 1; i <= RAA; i++) scenario.Add(new Child_RAA());
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldRemove_All()
        {
            scenario.RemoveAllOfType(typeof(IRoot));
            int remaining = 0;
            Assert.AreEqual(remaining, scenario.Count, DebugString(scenario));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldRemove_RB()
        {
            scenario.RemoveAllOfType(typeof(Child_RB));
            int remaining = sumofelements - RB;
            Assert.AreEqual(remaining, scenario.Count, DebugString(scenario));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldRemove_RA_AND_RAA()
        {
            scenario.RemoveAllOfType(typeof(Child_RA));
            int remaining = sumofelements - (RA + RAA);
            Assert.AreEqual(remaining, scenario.Count, DebugString(scenario));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just solved it 'return removeable.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType());' is how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
return removeable.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType());
```